# Question about Google+ Hangouts!

Tags: google-hangouts

Hey everyone so I have a few questions and I would really appreciate a response from those that are "100 factually certain of their answers" over someone who is merely speculating.

So I know that when I create my hangout, a URL is created for me to plug anywhere on line.

Is that URl for those to watch my hangout or to join it?

Also, who can join my Google+ hangout? Anyone? Only those with Gmail? Those with Google+?

Comment: Please limit your question posts to a single question. Also, please don't "sign" your posts. It would be a good idea for you to read our [help].

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a Hangout and NOT a Hangout On Air, then the URL will be to join the Hangout itself. (If you are creating a Hangout On Air, then there are two URLs. One will be to join the Hangout and one will be at youtube.com to view the Hangout.) There is no way from Google to just "watch" a non-on-air Hangout.

In either case, to join the hangout you need a Google+ account. If the person tries to join with a Google / GMail account, they will be asked to upgrade the account at that time and will be unable to join the hangout until they do.